# adding two or more xml files which have same structure as a child to another root element

Tags: java

I am using nu.xom java library, when adding the first xml root node to  element, i am getting "MultipleParentException". Can some one please provide solution, Thanks in advance.

Below are sample xml files:

```
<sqa>
  <element1>1<element1>
  <structelement>
     <element2>2<element2>
     <element2>2<element2>
  </structelement>
</sqa>
```

```
<sqa>
  <element1>4<element1>
  <structelement>
     <element2>5<element2>
     <element2>5<element2>
  </structelement>
</sqa>
```

output xml:

```
<root>
<sqa>
  <element1>1<element1>
  <structelement>
     <element2>2<element2>
     <element2>2<element2>
  </structelement>
</sqa>
<sqa>
  <element1>4<element1>
  <structelement>
     <element2>5<element2>
     <element2>5<element2>
  </structelement>
</sqa>
</root>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can't see the code that's causing the problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your xml as below

```
<sqa>
  <element1>1</element1>
  <structelement>
     <element2>2</element2>
     <element2>2</element2>
  </structelement>
</sqa>
```

```
<sqa>
  <element1>4</element1>
  <structelement>
     <element2>5</element2>
     <element2>5</element2>
  </structelement>
</sqa>
```

it seems you forgot the close the tags `element1` and `element2` to prevent reference of the previous document

And write code using `.copy()` method

```
Builder parser = new Builder();
        
Builder builder = new Builder();
Document root = builder.build("<root></root>", null);
        
Document doc = parser.build("aa.xml");
root.getRootElement().appendChild(doc.getRootElement().copy());
        
doc = parser.build("aa2.xml");
root.getRootElement().appendChild(doc.getRootElement().copy());
        
System.out.println(root.toXML());
```

You will get this output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><sqa>
  <element1>4</element1>
  <structelement>
     <element2>5</element2>
     <element2>5</element2>
  </structelement>
</sqa><sqa>
  <element1>1</element1>
  <structelement>
     <element2>2</element2>
     <element2>2</element2>
  </structelement>
</sqa></root>
```